# removing a "," from the last element in a foreach loop?

Tags: php

i am trying (like hell..) to remove ',' from the last element in a foreach loop.
tried several counter methods, but not really successfully.

```
[<?php

function fetchData($url){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch); 
  return $result;
  }

  $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/XXXXXXX/media/recent/?access_token=XXXXXXX&count=10");

  $result = json_decode($result);
  foreach ($result->data as $post) {
     echo '{"name":"Hello","imgpath":"  ';echo $post->images->low_resolution->url;echo '"},';

  }

?>]
```

Comment: Don't build json *by hand*. Collect your values in an associative array and use `json_encode`. Then the *comma-problem* vanishes.

Comment: The `json_encode` solution is correct, but for completeness: You don't need a counter, you just need to know if you're on the *first* element. The first element is the only one that doesn't have a comma *before* it. (A counter can't tell you what the last element is…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the whole thing in a string instead of echoing it, then you can cut the last character using `$string=substr($string,0,-1);`

```
[<?php

function fetchData($url){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch); 
  return $result;
}

$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/XXXXXXX/media/recent/?access_token=XXXXXXX&count=10");

$string="";

$result = json_decode($result);
foreach ($result->data as $post) {
     $string.='{"name":"Hello","imgpath":"' . $post->images->low_resolution->url . '"},';

}

echo substr($string,0,-1);

?>]
```

Comment: you could also use `rtrim($string,',')` but the correct tool for the job is `json_encode`

Comment: THX, balazs varga!

worked with

     $string.='{"name":"Hello","imgpath":"  '.$post->images->low_resolution->url.'"},';

Answer (score 4):

Use [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
<?php 
...

$json = array();
foreach ($result->data as $post){
    $json[]=array(
        'name'=>'Hello',
        'imgpath'=>$post->images->low_resolution->url,
    );
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
exit(json_encode($json));
?>
```

Comment: Alternatively, `json_encode(array_map(function($post){return array('name'=>'Hello','imgpath'=>$post->images->low_resolution->url);},$result->data));`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
// quick and dirty solution
foreach ($result->data as $index => $post) {
    $comma = ',';
    if ((int) $index === count($result->data) -1) {
        $comma = '';
    }
    $string.='{"name":"Hello","imgpath":"  ';echo $post->images->low_resolution->url;echo '"}'.$comma;
}
```

Comment: Why is this not useful, i tested this and it worked. What are you looking for?

Comment: just because it works does not mean its the correct way todo it, php has in-built functions for handling json, also it ugly

Comment: of course this is not the way to go but he probably wants a quick solution.. im not going to rewrite his whole code . thats up to him not me :)

Answer (score -1):

I would use implode, quite cleaner:

```
$result = json_decode($result);

$string = '{"name":"Hello","imgpath":"';
$string .= implode( '}, {"name":"Hello","imgpath":"', $result->data );
$string .= '}';

echo $string;
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but I think people are objecting to this approach because it is so clearly inferior to `json_encode`. Yes, [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it), but having clearly superior ways is something PHP desperately needs.

Comment: I agree, but, although this is a case of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378, the OP looks for an answer. Of course, the answer given by @Loz Cherone is the best, but I don't understand the quick downvotes